# Filter Context and Group by in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax

Consider the table with 2 columns which has a new row every time a user sign in. (Approximately 10M rows and can have duplicates as users can sign in multiple times per month)

| Sign in Month | MemberID |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-10 | 1000000 |
| 2020-12 | 1000001 |

Now to find out the unique user each month I can use the following query.

```
Select Sign_in_Month, count(distinct(memberid)) as unique_users from table group by Sign_in_Month
```

But I want to break the distinct count in the first query further into 2 cohorts where the user either sign in the last 3 month before or didn't. (**For October 2020 it would be July-Sep 2020 and for Sep 2020 it would be June-August 2020**)

I used to do this in powerBI through DAX which was easy with filter context but I am not sure how to implement this in SQL.

Desire Result

| Sign in Month | Total Unique Users | Unique Users who signed in in the last 3 months | Unique Users who did not sign in in the last 3 months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10 | 4000 | 3000 | 1000 |
| 2020-11 | 5000 | 2500 | 2500 |
| 2020-12 | 3500 | 1500 | 2000 |

The last 2 column should add up to the second column.

How do I create some sort of indicator as to where the member has shopped in the last 3 month **in reference to that particular month?**

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this as follows:

- Get a unique value per month.
- Use `lag()` to see the previous month when someone logged in.
- Compare the time difference.

For convenience, I would convert the `sign_in_month` to a date:

```
select sign_in_date,
       count(*) as num_members,
       sum(case when prev_sign_in_date >= dateadd(month, -4, sign_in_date)
                then 1 else 0 
           end) as num_members_who_signed_in
from (select t.memberId, v.sign_in_date,
             lag(v.sign_in_date) over (partition by t.memberId order by v.sign_in_date) as prev_sign_in_date
      from t cross apply
           (values (convert(date, t.sign_in_month, '-01'))
           ) v(sign_in_date)
      group by t.memberId, v.sign_in_date
     ) t
group by sign_in_date;
```

Note that `count(distinct)` is no longer needed because the subquery takes care of that.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff - that sub query using lag is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below script-

**Note**: syntax is for MSSQL, but the logic is global

```
select 
sign_in_month,
count(distinct MemberId) as total_unique_user,
count(
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(sign_in_month+'-01' as Date) >= DATEADD(mm,-4,getdate()) then MemberId
        else null
    end
) as last_3_month,
count(
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(sign_in_month+'-01' as Date) < DATEADD(mm,-4,getdate()) then MemberId
        else null
    end
) as before_3_month

from your_table_name
GROUP BY sign_in_month
```

Comment: Wouldn't using getdate just be referencing today's date rather from the date when the sign in happened?

Comment: Getdate() is Today (System/Server)

Comment: I have selected another answer as the solution as it is closer to what I wanted to achieve but would like to thank you for your input.

Comment: An up vote is better way to say thanks I think :)